# rails active_hash includes/joins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm using active_hash gem and I'm not sure if joins/includes is not supported, or I'm doing something wrong...

My models are : School (ActiveRecord) `belongs_to Commune` (ActiveHash) , and Region(ActiveHash) `has_many communes`

```
School.includes(:commune) 
NoMethodError: undefined method `type_for_attribute' for Commune:Class

School.joins(:commune)
NoMethodError: undefined method `table_name' for Commune:Class
```

Models :

Commune

```
class Commune < ActiveHash::Base
    include ActiveHash::Associations
    belongs_to :region    
    has_many :schools
end
```

School

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
    include ActiveHash::Associations
    attr_accessor :region
    extend ActiveHash::Associations::ActiveRecordExtensions
    belongs_to :commune
end
```

Region

```
class Region < ActiveHash::Base
    include ActiveHash::Associations
    has_many :communes
end
```

Documentation I read : https://github.com/zilkey/active_hash#referencing-activehash-objects-from-activerecord-associations

All operations like `School.last.commune.name` , `School.last.comune.region.name`, works perfectly

Regards!